# C# (.NET), how to fix web response performance, too much elapsed time

Tags: c#, html, .net, http, httpwebresponse

I'm need to optimize my code, elapsed time for response 1sec, elapsed time for ReadToEnd() it - 0.5sec, all other code (with full web request) take only 0.1sec.

```
request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

//This 1sec+
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

//This 0.5sec+
string mem = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

P.S: Html code about 200k+ chars, but i need only 4-5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on top of other's suggestions of using `using` and `setting proxy to null`, you might also want to try to only read a specific amount of chars, instead of reading everything.

```
var content = new char[10];
sr.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
string contentStr = new String(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, having not set the proxy settings for your `HttpWebResponse` is causing the delay. It is always recommended to set the proxy, even if its not used. Also try using the `using` clause:

```
request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

request2.Proxy = null;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string mem = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: doesn't help, same time (1.5-1.7 sec)

Answer (score 2):

The initial GetResponse call generates a security negotiation, Get and excecute, then an HTTP response whose first few bytes include the Http Response Code (200,500,404 etc).

The body of the response may already have been received by your client Http buffer or still be being streamed into it - you can't really tell. Your second call (readToEnd) reads all the bytes in the receive buffer and waits until the server has sent all the bytes indicated in the Http Header.

Your code is very unlikely to be causing any appreciable cost to the execution time of the web service call, and I can't see any likely optmisation steps - you need to determine how long the call takes without your client code.

Use Telerik Fiddler to track the number of bytes being called from the destination web service, and the amount of time the raw transfer from sever to client takes - do this by simply calling the URL within Fiddler or on a web browser. This will isolate whether its your code, or the server, or the connection latency costing time.

Comment: 205241 (get) + 1809 (post), 2.6 sec in web browser, 205219 + 1789, 2.1 sec in my client. So bytes length is same, but i dont need 205k from second response, i need take only one digit from whole html code, its impossible to get only part of code? Response always take all html page?

Comment: I think you might be missing a point here - how long does it take the Server to respond to the Get call ? This is why I recommend Fiddler - its free - and it will tell you how long it took for the first byte to be received back at your client - "time to first byte" and "time to last byte". You still dont know how long the transmission takes of the data, and how long the server takes creating the return data to send to you. The Fiddler "time to first byte" is the absolute minimum you will get your code down to - so its important to know it. You might find the 205k of data takes a trivial time.

Answer (score 0):

Check your js scripts doesnt depend on another services, repositories etc. It was worked for me before in my project. Download them and move it to your local folders